# Suggestions for How to Achieve Flexible Wireless Speaker System

Tags: product-recommendation, home-theater, speakers

I would like to have a set of wireless (they can be mains powered) speakers in my living room. I have indicated what I reckon will be the eventual position of the speakers in the plan below:

[image: My Living Room Plan]

There is a PC Desk on one side of the room, and while I am sat there gaming, watching video etc, I would like to use the two speakers (1 and 2) on the desk in a stereo arrangement when sat there.

When I sit on the sofa to watch film and TV on the projector (played through an old PC (PC 2) that is sat behind the sofa) or listen to music playing on my phone (or through PC 1), I would like to use speaker 2 and speaker 3 in a stereo arrangement.

Ideally, all three speakers would be the same manufacturer and I would really like to have some kind of flexible system where I can load up the positions of the three speakers and use an app or program on my phone or pc to set which ones to play with and combine.

I spoke to Sonos and they said that their speakers are not really designed to be used with a PC (which seems odd to me since that is where most of my music and watching is based).

Do you have any ideas how I might achieve the setup shown below? If not, can you think of a good approximation or similar setup that might be able to allow me to play music and games and films through a set of speakers with a flexible stereo setup? Even better, could I use speaker 3 as a single rear speaker when gaming? Any creative thoughts, recommendations of manufacture or even key words to search for would be really appreciated!

Comment: I think you're going to need some kind of audio amp like a home entertainment bar, to drive those speakers so far from the listener.  if your computer has a fiberoptic audio output you can use about any sound bar, but if your feeding it from the headphone jack that may require something special.  for the speaker switch, sound like a double pole double throw push button on speaker 2 to switch its input from one computer to the sound bar.

Comment: with cheap flat tvs these days, it seems odd to design a home theater around a projector.  Some very serious limitations  such as ambient light, people walking in front of the projector, image quality, noise from the projector fan right in front of you....

Comment: You are right about the projector, but that is not my choice at the moment. To be honest, I barely use it; I am much more likely to sit on the sofa reading a book and listening to music, but for the moment, the projector stays and that's that. It does work well and there is not actually a massive screen there - it projects onto the wall. As to the speakers, I take your point about the amp, I thought I might have to go in that direction. It is a small room, but still, it'll take a bit of work to fill it comfortably. I think I will have to stop trying to be so hi-tech!